# Speeding up a copy paste values for each loop

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have a code that works for me but is painfully slow given it copy and pastes for every loop (999 times) - its currently takes around 5 minutes. The reason for the copy and paste is that every loop enters a number into a model and it spits out new returns. These returns for the first copy and paste are just stored in another sheet on new rows. The second copy and paste is pasting values a few lines above itself so that on the next run the new values returned can be added to the old returns creating an aggregating effect (the formula in the range D36:EF41 is add the new values to the old pasted values). Is there anyway to speed either of these up?

Thanks for all your help!

```
'Row movement variable
RowNum1 = 11

    'Run macro through specified start site index to end site index
        For i = Sheets("Scenario Selector").Range("K10") To Sheets("Scenario Selector").Range("K11")
            Sheets("SITE Model").Range("C11").Value = i
            
            'Capture data from SITE Model
                Sheets("SITE Model").Range("C300:C306").Copy
                Sheets("Network Returns").Cells(RowNum1, ColNum1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    
                'Move paste down 1 row on each cycle
                    RowNum1 = RowNum1 + 1
    
            'Aggregate building copy paste
                Sheets("NETWORK Model").Range("D36:EF41").Copy
                Sheets("NETWORK Model").Range("D25").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to improve performance.

1. **The practical way**

As you are pasting huge amounts of data into your workbook Excel must integrate all of it and display the result. Therefore `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`. You can toggle the latter with `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` to allow calculations after each loop, for example, if the results are required by the next loop. Return both settings to their original at the end of the program.

2. **A conceptual change**

You are just using an Excel spreadsheet as an array. Of course it can be replaced with an VBA array. The two are structural cousins and enjoy perfect relations with each other.

```
Dim Arr As Variant
Arr = Sheets("NETWORK Model").Range("D36:EF41").Value
```

The above will transfer all the data to an array from which you could then read data into another array a thousand times faster than you can write them to a sheet. You might then paste your final array to a sheet with a single command.

So, what does the final (or intermediate) output look like? Prepare it in memory as an array and assign that array to the Value property of a sheet range. You'll be done in seconds - very few of them - not minutes.

Comment: Variatus, very nice! One question, I noted the use of Variant for the array. Is this required for it to work or should the array be typed to the type of data for efficiency?

Comment: Jack, if you pursue this I'd recommend this article by Chip Pearson: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/VBAArrays.htm it contains a function to transpose a VBA array along with many other VBA array functions.

Comment: Excel uses the Variant type for all cell contents. Therefore `Dim Arr As Variant: Arr = Range("A1:ZZ10000").Value` or `Arr=Cells(1, 1).Value` is standard fare. Both take about the same time to execute. So there is an obvious speed-up. But either one is many times slower than `MyVariant = Arr(999, 15)`. Therefore you want to replace as many of the former with as many of the latter as you can. It's not a requirement but an option.

Answer (score 0):

Jack, the only thing I can see that would speed up your code is to declare (DIM) you worksheets so they don't have to be resolved every time they are referenced in your code.

```
Dim shtSrc as Worksheet
Dim shtDst As Worksheet
Dim shtSS  As Worksheet
Dim shtNM  As Worksheet

Set shtSrc = Sheets("SITE Model")
Set shtDst = Sheets("Network Returns")
Set shtSS  = Sheets("Scenario Selector")
Set shtNM  = Sheets("NETWORK Model")

'Row movement variable
RowNum1 = 11

    'Run macro through specified start site index to end site index
        For i = shtSS.Range("K10") To shtSS.Range("K11")
            shtSrc.Range("C11").Value = i
            
            'Capture data from SITE Model
                shtSrc.Range("C300:C306").Copy
                shtDst.Cells(RowNum1, ColNum1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    
                'Move paste down 1 row on each cycle
                    RowNum1 = RowNum1 + 1
    
            'Aggregate building copy paste
                shtNM.Range("D36:EF41").Copy
                shtNM.Range("D25").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you! That trimmed about a minute of the full 9 minute cycle! I was reading that i should be using = instead of copy and paste but not sure of that will work in this case...

Answer (score 0):

Jack, to follow up on Variatus's answer, which intrigued me, I wrote a test program to figure out the details.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub Test()

Dim arrSrc() As Variant
Dim arrDst() As Variant
Dim shtSrc As Worksheet
Dim shtDst As Worksheet
Dim rngDst As Range
Dim lRowCntr As Long
Dim lColCntr As Long

Set shtSrc = Sheets("SourceData")
Set shtDst = Sheets("NewData")

'*** Range below could be calculated with code!
arrSrc = shtSrc.Range("A1:E5").Value

ReDim arrDst(UBound(arrSrc, 1), UBound(arrSrc, 2))

For lRowCntr = LBound(arrSrc, 1) To UBound(arrSrc, 1)

   For lColCntr = LBound(arrSrc, 2) To UBound(arrSrc, 2)
   
      arrDst(lRowCntr, lColCntr) = arrSrc(lRowCntr, lColCntr) * 2
      
   Next lColCntr

Next lRowCntr

Set rngDst = Range(shtDst.Cells(1, 1), shtDst.Cells(UBound(arrDst, 1), UBound(arrDst, 2)))

'*** Write Array back to worksheet
'*** Use Offset to locate dest upperleft cell to target!
rngDst.Offset(10, 10) = arrDst  '*** Write starting at K11

End Sub 'Test
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you! I'll be honest and say these are very new concepts to me, so I am not entirely sure what is going on in the above! I will try and figure it out! A few seconds is definitely faster than my 8 minutes!